# Laravel 5 on two vps server and one domain name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dns, vps

I have a laravel (with mysql) project that uses Jobs, cron tasks, etc. I want to configure it on two different vps servers(two mysql db How can they be synchronized?), but so that the load is distributed evenly. And he use one domain name.

example.com - domain

127.0.0.1 - 1 vps server with isp manager

127.0.0.2 - 2 vps server with isp manager

how to set up a domain to work with two servers?
 How can this be done?

upd

I use this if one of the servers stops working. I need to configure this at the domain level.

Comment: I think you should look into load balancers? Then you would point your domain to load balancer , where load balancer would distribute traffic to different servers. I think you would then have 2 copies of your laravel app on both VPS servers which would connect to external DB or 1 would be local, 1 external. It is one of the ways, but it can be wrong way to go and it really depends on your application

Answer (score 0):

You can point 1 of the projects to the other projects DB, just edit the .env to the internal ip address of the project who has the DB, but i recommend you a third vps just for the DB, then point both projects to that VPS, then you can add a loadbalancer VPS too and handle the traffic for the projects vps instances.

Answer (score 0):

It's slb what you need, you can implement lsb functionality with nginx reverse proxy

```
http {
    upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1;
        server 127.0.0.2;
    }
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
    }
}
```

refer https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/

Comment: I use this if one of the servers stops working. I need to configure this at the domain level.